# Are there any good pull request clients for Bitbucket?

Tags: plugins, bitbucket, review

We use bitbucket a lot, especially using the pull requests mechanism to review and approve changes.

I find it very hard for me to review pull requests using the web-based interface of bitbucket, and would like to be able to review them in something a bit more "smart", which allows me to jump to files quickly and navigate from usage to declaration of variables fast.

I could not find a tool which can do such a thing.

Did anyone hear \ made a tool that can do such thing?

Comment: Bitbucket Server or Bitbucket Cloud?

Comment: Bitbucket Cloud

Answer (score 1):

You can try this addon. It allows you easily manage pull requests. All PRs will be in a board where you can drag them into proper status (in preparation, ready for review, reviewing etc).
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/1221505